# How to put login form in Cms Page in Magento?

Tags: magento

I want to add a login form to CMs page in Magento, I have tried adding this:

```
{{block type=”core/template”  template=”customer/form/login.phtml”}}
```

in the `content` section of the CMS page, but its not working .  Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code finally wordked for me .

```
{{block type ="Mage_Customer_Block_Form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open cms.xml in your theme and find the following

```
<reference name="content">
<block type=”cms/page” name=”cms_page”/>
</reference>
```

Replace it with this

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml"/>
<block type=”cms/page” name="cms_page"/>
</reference>
```

Then your code should work.

Comment: I think ,what I'm asking is also possible without editing CMS.xml.

Answer (score 0):

If your magento version less than 1.6 use the below code.

```
{{block type="customer/login" template="customer/form/login.phtml"}}
```

if your Magento version is 1.6 or greater

```
{{block type="customer/login" template="persistent/customer/form/login.phtml"}}
```

Comment: This code also didn't helped.So I myself figured it out.Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login_block" template="persistent/customer/form/login.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it without modifying any files:

Go into the Design tab
In "Custom Layout Update XML" add the following:

> < reference name="content">
>   
> < block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" after="-"/>
>   
> < /reference>

There you go. You can also do this in Categories.

Tested in Magento 1.8.1 (should work on most versions)